# Methods removing elements and duplicates from array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Consider code given below:

```
public class Lista {

private int[] numbers;
private int capacity;
private int size;

public Lista (int capacity) {
    this.size = 0;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.numbers = new int[capacity];
}

public void addElement(int element) {
    if (size == capacity) {
        System.out.println("Array numbers is full");
        return;
    }
    numbers[size++] = element;
        }

 public void removeFirst(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == x) {
            for (int y = i; y < size; y++) {
                numbers[y] = numbers[y + 1];
            } break;
        } size--;
    }
}

public void removeDuplicates() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
                for (int y = j; y < size; y++) {
                    numbers[y] = numbers[y + 1];
                } size--;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista lista = new Lista(10);
    lista.addElement(1);
    lista.addElement(2);
    lista.addElement(3);
    lista.addElement(2);
    lista.addElement(5);
    lista.addElement(2);
    lista.addElement(7);
```

Regarding methods removeFirst and removeDuplicates is there better way (faster, more clear) than structures that i've used? 
The removeFirst method is supposed to remove the first ocurrence of int given as the argument.
The removeDuplicates method is supposed to remove any duplicates from the array.
I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Are you sure these actually work correctly? It looks like `removeFirst` will remove *all* occurrences of `x`, not just the first. You should focus on correctness first, performance after.

Comment: You are correct, added `break` just outside of the inne for loop. Also moved `size--` just outside the if loop.

Comment: Update your code above with what you have now. Your remove first code can also be done using only 1 loop. And I assume you are not allowed to use existing Java Data Structures such as Maps and Sets?

Comment: I don't have any restrictions. Doing task i found on the internet, and i haven't studied maps and sets yet so i i just did it the way i was able to.

Comment: `} size--;` and `} break;` on one line are not proper formatting.

Comment: Sorting the array before calling `removeDuplicates` could make it more efficient. With a sorted array, once the values start getting above the value you're removing duplicates of, you can move on to the next rather than having to compare each value to every following value.

Comment: In `removeFirst`, `} size--;` the decrement outside the `if` will mess up your results. (Proper formatting would make this mistake easier to diagnose.)

Comment: When removing an element, you could use `System.arraycopy` to move the following elements down instead of coding a `for` loop.  It saves a couple lines of code and is likely to be faster as well.  Check out the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the comments:

```
    public void removeFirst(int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] == x) {
//                for (int y = i; y < size; y++) {
//                    numbers[y] = numbers[y + 1];
//                }
                System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, numbers, i, size - i);
                size--;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeDuplicates() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
//                    for (int y = j; y < size; y++) {
//                        numbers[y] = numbers[y + 1];
//                    }
                    System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, numbers, i, size - i);
                    size--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `j--` to the if statement, because it wasn't working properly when there were same numbers one after another in the array. Now it works fine. Thanks!

```
public void removeDuplicates() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
             }
                System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, numbers, i, size - i);
                size--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```